# Cost of reading and sorting 10GB table at cloud providers

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, aws

Say I have a 10 GB table and I need to read it and then sort it by some column. How much does such an operation cost at cloud providers, say AWS or Azure if the pricing is variable? I just need a very rough estimate... is it 10 cents, 10 dollars or 100 dollars?

Comment: It's probably something like 0.001 cents. Getting your 10 GB table up there though would cost anywhere from 0 to $5000, depending on how you plan to do it.

Comment: @mustaccio: can you explain a bit more? That is a large interval...

Comment: Explain what part exactly?

Comment: @mustaccio why it can vary so much, i.e. example of a couple of factors...

Comment: What mustaccio means is there's multiple costs involved with using a cloud service that are too complicated to answer in general, or even in detail on StackExchange. You'd have to talk to a representative to get a better picture. Essentially there are so many options on how to store the data in the cloud, move it into that storage in the beginning, to replicate it (if you choose to), and to access it. Each of those points have multitudes of options costing magnitudes in different pricings.

Comment: If you do it once, most providers have free tiers and free trials of whatever you can use to sort 10GB of foobar; that's $0. If you do it all the time you'll have to maintain this whatever for whatever it costs at a particular provider at a particular time of day. For any value of whatever.

Comment: why not just create a clustered index on some column that sorts your data the way you want it so the sort is free?

Comment: @ErikDarling, it is just a hypothetical question. I am trying to understand how much cloud computation costs.

Comment: that's okay, it was just a hypothetical suggestion for reducing your hypothetical costs.

Comment: @ErikDarling, is your book Great Post only available on Amazon? The print version....

Comment: as far as i know. you might also be able to get it at a local soup kitchen with some hardtack and watered down rum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database has a Serverless tier that's charged by the second, so this is pretty easy to estimate.

I took AdventureWorksDW and appended enough copies of FactInternetSales to make a table that's about 10GB. It was about 26M rows.  And ran it on a 4 vCore database that costs about $0.03 Minute:

[image]

Plus about $6/month for data storage:

[image]

Then ran

```
select top 100 *
from FactInternetSales_10GB
order by SalesAmount desc
```

Here's the plan

[image]

And it executed in 49 seconds:

```
 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 90469 ms,  elapsed time = 48828 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

So

> is it 10 cents, 10 dollars or 100 dollars?

It's in the 10 cents order of magnitude, but the data storage is in the $10/month range.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this depends on the exact service being used within each cloud provider itself, not just the difference in pricing between cloud providers. I've worked in AWS for Microsoft SQL Server, on instances both using **RDS** and normal **EC2** server instances (forget the exact name) and the pricing varies wildly just within AWS itself.

So unfortunately this question has a big *it depends* kind of answer, because honestly it could cost anywhere between 10 cents and 100 dollars realistically, depending on the specific cloud service provider, the service within that provider, and the quality of provisioning of that service you pay for.

One thing that's probably universally true is cloud service providers don't save you costs (as much as their marketing might lead you to believe) vs an on prem solution, in most cases. Rather they just improve stability, maintainability, and generally improve your own workflow.

Comment: Thanks, say I want the fastest solution. Will that help with a better estimate?

Comment: The fastest solution at the point of diminishing returns for only 10 GB of data, at a very rough guess, could cost you somewhere in the thousands to tens of thousands of dollars. Now that's just for a one time use, but cloud providers charge fees on a timeframe basis, so it makes more sense to look at it for a given timeframe (i.e. to even just store the data).